# Not able to build war in maven project

Tags: web-applications, maven

Couple of issues :In for my maven project in Eclipse Run as -- Run on Server is not coming.
                  2)So i want to run in directly in tomcat server ,wo when i try to  create war the following error is coming up .please help me out , i  have my web.xml in the specified path only

```
   Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war)
 on project SchoolMgmtApp: The specified web.xml file 
'F:\WorkSpace\SchoolMgmtApp\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml' does not exist -
```

Answer (score 23):

I think the error is self-explaining. You have no `web.xml` in your project. Is this intended?  In theory you can have a WAR file without a `web.xml` file as Servlet 3.0 supports this kind of deployments. In this case you have to configure the maven-war-plugin like this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: web.xml is thier inn the specified path

Comment: So the file is there but Maven complains about it is not? Perhaps a file permission issue?

Comment: Yes, of course, as the docs explicitly state failOnMissingWebXml is required. An extra thumbs up to chkal for mentioning the Servlet 3.0 exception, this is spot on!

Answer (score 5):

Your web.xml may not be in a standard location.  Some Eclipse project creation wizards put web.xml in WebContent/WEB_INF.  In this case you can rearrange the project so that maven likes it, or you can tell maven where to find your web.xml in the pom.xml.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <webXml>WebContent\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your looking for something like this:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <warName>${applicationContextName}</warName>
        <packagingExcludes>
            AFolder,
            aFile.xml
        </packagingExcludes>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-war</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>war</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```